# Laravel validation required_if other field has at least X values

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a field that I want to be required (and validated) only if another field (an array) has at least 2 values.
I have this `productListArray` field which need to have a `brandId` column only if `bandsId` has at least 2 values.

I tried something like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($inputFields, [
          'brandsId' => 'required|array|min:1',
          'brandsId.*' => 'required|uuid', 
          'productListArray' => 'required|array|min:1',
          'productListArray.*.name' => 'required|string',
          'productListArray.*.brandId' => 'required_if:brandsId,min:2|uuid'
      ]);
```

But this doesn't seem to validate anything since I don't get any error when I try to send 2 values in brandsId and no brandId column in productListArray.
Should I write a custom rule or is it possible with builtIn features?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix this when adding an extra simple validation rule like this:

```
$validator->sometimes('productListArray.*.brandId', 'required', function ($input) {
        return count($input->brandsId) > 1;
      });
```

This way I'm requiring this extra column only when brandsId count is greater than 1